# Django: Appending certain values after updating model

Tags: python, django

I was wondering how I could make this work.

I'm currently doing this Django project that creates and modifies Client models, as such:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField('birth date')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True)
    medical_condition = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
    experience = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=EXPERIENCE, blank=True)
    next_class = models.DateTimeField('next class')
```

Now, everything is pretty much working fine. I'm currently using generic form views to create and update students, so that's fine. However, I'm planning on doing a View where I can see a financial report of all the students who have taken classes, payments included. How would I go along with this? I could try somehow appending next_class to a dictionary of some sort each time I change its value, but I feel that's not efficient at all.

I've tried to see how I can do this; I was mostly thinking of using Django's Admin history app and integrating it to my actual webpage, but I found out about [Simple History](https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history) which seems pretty good. I feel like it doesn't exactly do the queries I want, though.

Thanks in advance, and I apologize if it's vague in any way. I can update my post with more code if necessary, just didn't want to make this question much longer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what your question is here. Are you asking how to query all Clients with `next_class` in the past?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Are you talking about custom queries?

Comment: Yeah, sorry! As `next_class` is a variable, overwriting the variable means I can't use it. For example a student wants to take a class this Thursday, December 10th. If I try using generic form views in order to update next_class, the previous value I had for December 3rd is overwritten. Sorry this is a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model is wrong. It seems like you need a separate related model for the classes that a student takes. It could be as simple as:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client')
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

so that instead of changing a field in the Client model, you add a new row to the Class model. Then it will be fairly simple to query all classes for a client between two dates:

```
classes_taken = my_client.class_set.filter(date_range=[start_date, end_date])
```

where `my_client` is an instance of Client, and `start_date` and `end_date` are the relevant dates.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but the classes don't have an explicit beginning and ending date, per se. For example: John gets registered in a class on December 15th at 3:00pm, and now wants to take another on January 3rd at 1:00pm, and another class on January 8th, 5:00pm. How could I store both values All I want is to store all past and future classes so I can access them later on a list or dictionary of some sort. I'm not sure if this is possible. This is why I'm trying to use `next_class` rather than a separate model.